# Установка значений размера для формы

Tags: java, swing, gui

Мне необходимо создать диалог с `Jlist` и `JscrollPane`, чтобы они были фиксированного размера, но сама форма получается правильного размера, а `JScrollPane` только в одну строку:

```
private void InitializeGUI(){
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setSize(325,625);
    setMinimumSize(getSize());
    setMaximumSize(getSize());
    JList list1 = new JList();
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    String[] strings = HelpArg.getHelpStrings();
    for (String s : strings) {
        listModel.addElement(s);
    }
    list1.setModel(listModel);
    list1.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list1.setSize(300,600);
    list1.setMinimumSize(list1.getSize());
    list1.setMaximumSize(list1.getSize());
    contentPane.setSize(300,300);
    contentPane.setMinimumSize(contentPane.getSize());
    contentPane.setMaximumSize(contentPane.getSize());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list1);
    scrollPane.setSize(300,600);
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPane.getSize());
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(scrollPane.getSize());
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    add(contentPane);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел на разные Layout для JFrame и выбрал тот, который лучше подходит, почитать про них можно тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`java.awt.FlowLayout` который использует `JPanel`, если ей не указан другой layout, игнорирует все размеры, кроме предпочитаемого (preferred size).

Варианты следующие:

1. Не использовать layout вообще:

   ```
   contentPane = new JPanel( null );
   ```

   В этом случае управление размером и положением компонентов на панели целиком возлагается на ваш код (с использованием `setLocation` и `setSize`).
2. Задать предпочитаемый размер:

   ```
   list1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 600 ) );
   ```
3. Перестать заморачиваться абсолютными размерами, выбрать подходящий layout и позволить ему работать.